# Developing Libre Office extensions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, libreoffice

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Extension_Development

writes that it is possible to develop Libre Office extensions in JavaScript.

However, the suggested

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development

does not list any JavaScript tutorial for that.

https://www.openoffice.org/framework/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html

says that this is experimental.

Is there any serious example of writing a JS extension for Libre Office?

And, a good tutorial on that?

Comment: Yes, it is experimental, so there are no serious examples of writing a JS extension.  However it can be done by following the instructions in the www.openoffice.org link above.  (I also posted a "Hello World" example on stackoverflow for Calc but apparently it got deleted).  If you run into specific problems then feel free to post another question.  Any reason you want to try JS rather than using a mature macro-enabled language such as Java, Basic or Python?

Comment: @JimK    My idea is to experiment with the functional language ML as there is a compiler from ML to JS. But probably I should try to interface ML directly to Libre Office. Would it be a large endeavour?

Answer (score 5):

This simple JavaScript code reads the values two cells and write the result to one of them.

```js
// Import standard OpenOffice.org API classes. For more information on
// these classes and the OpenOffice.org API, see the OpenOffice.org
// Developers Guide at:
// http://api.libreoffice.org/

importClass(Packages.com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime);
importClass(Packages.com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument);
importClass(Packages.com.sun.star.container.XIndexAccess);
importClass(Packages.com.sun.star.table.XCellRange);
importClass(Packages.com.sun.star.table.XCell);

// Get the document object from the scripting context
oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument();
// Get the XSpreadsheetDocument interface from the document
xSDoc = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetDocument, oDoc);
// Get the XIndexAccess interface used to access each sheet
xSheetsIndexAccess = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XIndexAccess, xSDoc.getSheets());

// Get sheet 1
xSheet = xSheetsIndexAccess.getByIndex(0); // base 0 for sheet 1
// Get the XCellRange interface used to access a cell
xCll = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCellRange, xSheet);

// Get interfaces to cells A9 and K9
xCell_A9 = xCll.getCellByPosition(0,8); // base 0 for A9
xVar_A9 = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCell, xCell_A9);

xCell_K9 = xCll.getCellByPosition(10,8); // base 0 for K9
xVar_K9 = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCell, xCell_K9);

// Get the value of the A9 and K9 cells
varA9 = xVar_A9.getValue();
varK9 = xVar_K9.getValue();

// Write the sum of A9 and K9 to A9
xVar_A9.setValue(varA9 + varK9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LibreOffice 6.0, I'm able to create and run a JavaScript macro in a Calc (spreadsheet) document.

Its a goal-seeking macro and there's lots of calculations involved, so its pretty damn slow.

Because I don't trust the built-in editor, especially with lack of "Undo" and distrust over the "Save" functionality, I'm editing the macro in Atom, and copy-paste into LibreOffice's script editor.

Note:  I'm most comfortable in JavaScript, of the scripting languages available, so I used that.

Oh, and yes I know I'm not yet providing much useful information, but I hope to do that later.